# Read all lines from file

Tags: f#

I want to read all the lines from the file and implement acquired the following:

```
 let s1 = File.ReadAllText("\\test.txt")

   let splitArr = s1.Split[|' '|] |> Array.toList
   let checkList = check splitArr
   let final = String.concat " " checkList |> toLower |> makeUpper
   Console.Write(final)
```

I even tried to looping through the file but perhaps did wrong:

```
        let myfile = File.OpenText("\\test.txt")       
         let fileLoop() = 
                 let s1 = myfile.ReadLine()              
                 let splitArr = s1.Split[|' '|] |> Array.toList
                 let checkList = check splitArr
                 let final = String.concat " " checkList |> toLower |> upper
                 Console.Write(s1)
         while fileLoop() do ignore None
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I cant read all line and do this following:
2. Transforms it into a list of words,
3. Tries to interpret the list of word as either a claim or a question,
4. If interpreted as claim, prints the corresponding question on the screen,
5. If interpreted as question, prints the corresponding claim on the screen,
6. If failing to interpret the list of words, then terminates. Otherwise repeats from 1.

I just need to read all line by looping and make something with it. But how it looks now, I cant read all line by looping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your existing code bears little resemblance with your textual description of what you are trying to achieve. Ignoring that, a simple observation to make your current code work: You are using `File.ReadAllText`, which returns a giant blob of text - but you are afterwards assuming it comes already separated by lines. Use one of the methods in the `File` module that returns the text linewise, that is `ReadLines` or `ReadAllLines`. Try the following:

```
File.ReadLines("\\test.txt")
|> Seq.iter (fun s1 ->
    let splitArr = s1.Split[|' '|] |> Array.toList
    let checkList = check splitArr
    let final = String.concat " " checkList |> toLower |> makeUpper
    Console.WriteLine(final)
)
```

Or making heavier use of pipes:

```
File.ReadLines "\\test.txt"
|> Seq.iter (fun s1 ->
    s1.Split [|' '|] 
    |> Array.toList
    |> check
    |> String.concat " "
    |> toLower 
    |> makeUpper
    |> Console.WriteLine
)
```